# How to make dynamic call when checkBox select All selected per TabPage per datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

I have added dynamic tabs which have dynamic datagrid having DataGridCheckBoxColumn and also a dynamic checkBox on the tab which triggers selects all for datagrid checkboxes.

I am trying to implement something along these line.

```
private void cbSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (cbSelectAll.Checked)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in relatedPatientsDG.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Value = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in relatedPatientsDG.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Value = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But this method is to be dynamic as well which needs to verify which tab/datagrid DataGridCheckBoxColumn was selected because I am creating everything dynamically on the tab.

As an example if I have a dataGrid called relatedDG have DataGridColumnCheckBox then the events method to trigger select all and unselect all would be like. I need to make a similar change but for dynamic datagridcheckbox so nothing is hardcoded.

```
private void cbSelectAllSameVisits_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbSelectAllSameVisits.Checked)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in relatedDG.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Value = true;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in relatedDG.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Value = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the fact that each pair of a grid and a checkbox is on the same tabpage - they are both children of the same container control.

This allows you to have a single method that you attach to the `CheckedChanged` event of all the checkboxes on creation:

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    DataGridView dg = cb.Parent.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                        .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(DataGridView))
                        .FirstOrDefault() as DataGridView;

    if (dg != null)
    {              
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells[0].Value = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells[0].Value = false;
            }
        }           
    }            
}
```

That code uses the sender parameter of the event handler to identify the checkbox that was clicked then searches through the controls belonging that that checkboxes parent for the first DataGridView.